# Vectorization of nested for loop

Tags: r, vectorization

I have the following function:

```
g.Bn = function(n) {
  Bn = 0
  for(k in 0:n) {
    res.of.loop = 0
    for(j in 0:k) {
      res.of.loop = res.of.loop + (-1)^j * (j + 1)^n * choose(k, j)
    }
    Bn = res.of.loop * 1/(k+1) + Bn
  }
  return(Bn)
}
```

Is here a way to vectorize it instead of using for loops?

Comment: You could try replacing the inner loop with `j<-0:k; 
    res.of.loop<- sum((-1)^j * (j + 1)^n * choose(k, j))`

Comment: Should modified `g.Bn` be a vectorized function? Meaning a function that returns a vector of answers when provided with a vector of input?

Comment: @slava-kohut Maybe my question was unclear. I want to use vector operations but the returned value should still be a real number.

Comment: Oh wait. You could implement in c. That might well lead to substantial speed improvements.

Answer (score 4):

You could vectorise the inner loop (as per @DaveT), and use sapply:

```
g.Bn2 = function(n) {
  sum(sapply(0:n, function(k) {
    sum((-1)^(0:k) * (0:k + 1)^n * choose(k, 0:k)) * 1/(k+1)
  }))
}
```

Or another possibility to vectorise the outer loop:

```
g.Bn3 = function(n) {
  f <- function(k, n) sum((-1)^(0:k) * (0:k + 1)^n * choose(k, 0:k)) * 1/(k+1)
  sum(Vectorize(f, vectorize.args = "k")(0:n, n))
}
```

```
> microbenchmark(g.Bn(100), g.Bn2(100), g.Bn3(100))
       expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
  g.Bn(100) 1493.086 1533.9280 1841.3455 1585.354 1675.3575 9023.316   100
 g.Bn2(100)  617.063  650.7850  905.6899  738.230  788.7305 9224.460   100
 g.Bn3(100)  685.094  772.3785 1015.9182  816.945  860.1775 8213.777   100
```

Comment: Tried your code, and `g.Bn2` (`g.Bn3`) produces different results after `n` passes some threshold. Try `g.Bn(15)` and `g.Bn2(15)`. Why is that?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure, but I think precision somehow. I can't say which approach is better in this regard.

Comment: Id guess this may be to do with floating point arithmetic ... try doing it on the log scale?

Comment: @waferthin Thanks for replying. I found that just using DaveT's approach for the innerloop and leaving the outer loop as is gives me a better microbenchmark result than any of your solutions. Why do you think that is? Does sapply just iterate in similar fashion to a loop?

`g.Bn = function(n) {
  Bn = 0
  for(k in 0:n) {
    j = c(0:k)
    res.of.loop = sum((-1)^j * (j + 1)^n * choose(k, j))
    Bn = Bn + res.of.loop * 1/(k+1)
  }
  return(Bn)
}`

Comment: Yes the real speed improvement here can be achieved with vectorisation of the inner loop. All other changes are really just different forms of looping (arguably with nicer syntax but no real speed gain). I think the only way to speed up any more would be to think about whether the equations could be simplified in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `for-loop` to `map` and `reduce` instead.

In the example below `purrr::map` iterate all data, and `sum` reduces a numeric vector into a scaler(a numeric vector with length of one).

```
g.Bn = function(n) {
    sum(
        purrr::map_dbl(0:n,function(k){
            sum(
                purrr::map_dbl(0:k,function(j){
                    (-1)^j * (j + 1)^n * choose(k, j)
                })
            ) * 1/(k+1)

        })
    )
}
```

And it seems like all `j`s in inner loop can be replaced with `0:k`

```r
g.Bn = function(n) {
    sum(
        purrr::map_dbl(0:n,function(k){
            sum((-1)^(0:k) * (0:k + 1)^n * choose(k, 0:k)) * 1/(k+1)
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: Two `for` replaced by two `purrr::`. And both are using iteration. What makes it be more powerful? I am not criticizing. I am asking seriously.

Comment: Using `purrr::` saves the trouble of assigning initializer variables at least. And for me, the logic on each level is pretty clear by using nested anonymous function.